# Calculate direction of a vehicle (Veins/Omnet++/Sumo)

Tags: omnet++, veins

Is it possible to calculate(get) direction of vehicle in Veins(via TraCIMobility)? I want to know if two vehicles are traveling in opposing directions or not. I think I can do that via [getAngleRad()](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h#L113) method (if they are moving in the same direction they fall in the same quadrant and if moving opposite they are in opposite quadrants), but I am not sure if its correct. 
(Sub-Question: Also, what are the exact values that getAngleRad() would return
for each quadrant?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: `getAngleRad()` returns the vehicle's heading in radians (from `-pi` up to, but excluding, `+pi`). A value of `0` means the vehicle is heading east; a value of `pi/2` means it is heading north; etc.