# Get steering angle information from Veins or SUMO into OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am implementing a Kalman Filter based prediction model to estimate vehicular position in future time-steps. For accurate estimation I am thinking of using position, speed and steering angle as inputs.

Currently, Veins provides position and speed as inputs through `BasicSafetyMessage` message. Is there a way to obtain steering angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the absolute direction of the vehicle using getAngleRad() as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975250/calculate-direction-of-a-vehicle-veins-omnet-sumo) but currently SUMO does not provide a steering angle so I doubt Veins does. This is not only a limitation of the interface but also of the underlying models which simply do not need that information so it is not modeled explicitly. You may of course interpolate something by using the difference of the last two absolute angles.